# Show the value of a field when onMouseOver?

Tags: html, css

I have several inputs on the same row of a table. some of them eventually are "small" (or short).
Particularly the **INPUT DATE** field value is very difficult to see because the allowed is shorter than the "10 characters + the calendar icon".

So, I would like to do a onMouseOver display the current value of the field. **After user changes, it shows the newest value user selected.**

How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: are you using any JS frameworks like Angular, react?

Comment: You can set input attribute `title` and then value will appear on mouse over of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the date into javascript variable as `datetime` format.
2. If you are using hardcode HTML and CSS you can use tooltip.
   Refer here :https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp
3. If you are using frameworks such as Angular. Just use `MatTooltip`

Answer (score 0):

You can add events to the input by using JavaSCript. In this solution, I used two events: `mouseover` and `mouseout` to display/hide a tooltip.

So basically the input value is hidden until the `mouseover` event is trigged.

The CSS styles are available on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp)

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const output = document.getElementById("output")
input.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  output.innerHTML = input.value
  output.classList.add("active")
})
input.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  output.classList.remove("active")
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Your inputs below</h1>
<div class="tooltip"> 
  <input id="input" type="date"></input>
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="output"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it.

```
<input type="text" id="userType" title="title show while hovering the field" />
```